# Why does removing items from an arraylist that fullfill one of the two conditions not work?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Ok so I have an integer ArrayList from which I want to remove the entries that are either odd or are bigger than 100.
My code, however, does not work and I do not really get why?

```
list.add(1);
        list.add(899);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(647);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(804);
        list.add(103);
        ArrayList<Integer> list2  = removeEntries(list);

public static ArrayList<Integer> removeEntries(ArrayList<Integer> list1) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            while(list1.get(i) % 2 != 0 || list1.get(i) > 100) {
                if(i != list1.size()) list1.remove(i);
            }
        }
        return list1;
    }
```

This does not give me the right list2-entries but I do not understand as to why...

Comment: your entire method can be rewritten als: List<Integer> list2 = list1.stream().filter(i -> (i%2) == 0 && !(i > 100) ).collect(Collectors.toList()); keeping code minimal makes it easier to maintain

Comment: For starters `i != list1.size()` is always true, so you will remove every element in the list. Also `while` is a loop, perhaps you meant `if`? And lastly, you should learn how to use your IDE's debugger, it's invaluable skill, and the problem with the code will be obvious.

Comment: @Chaosfire that if is pretty irrelevant. He put his actual relevant conditions in the while block

Comment: @Stultuske It's only irrelevant if it doesn't change behavior.

Comment: @DaveNewton a condition that always returns true? pretty irrelevant

Comment: @Stultuske Oh, I think I misunderstood your point. It's still not irrelevant, because the OP thinks it's doing something *important*, which it isn't; *my* point is that it does affect runtime behavior, but not the way the OP thinks it does. Minimal code also doesn't equal easier maintenance; it *may*, but it's far from a guarantee. It's more important to have readable code--what that means varies between devs.

Comment: @Stultuske Depends on why it was put there in the first place. If it is meant to be insurance against `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, as i suspect it is, then it is pretty relevant(relevant in the way that it doesn't do it's intended job).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `List#removeIf`

Use the [`Collection#removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) method, inherited by `List`. Pass a `Predicate` with your criteria for removal.

Like this:

```
list.removeIf(x -> x != null && (x % 2 == 1 || x > 100));
System.out.println(list);  // [4]
```

Comment: true, but now you alter the content of the original List, which is a change in functionality.

Comment: @Stultuske The original code modifies the original list as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop in your method is incorrect, this should be an `if`:

```java
List<Integer> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer i : list1) {
    if (i % 2 == 0 && i < 100) {
        filteredList.add(i);
    }
}
return filteredList;
```

Pretty sure using `remove()` while you're iterating through a collection will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: You may want to explain how and why you completely changed the original code.

Comment: `remove()` won't throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, because iteration is done with indexes, not with enhanced for loop. But it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, the index is not updated after removal(which is error prone operation anyway, and has better alternatives)